# Docker container raises error but github actions was passed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, github-actions, cicd

I'm building and running tests inside containers and I expected when some test container fail, the running stop raising the error.

Action example:

```yaml
name: Test

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  run-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Build and run
        run: |
          docker-compose --env-file=compose.env --file=compose-tests.yaml down --remove-orphans
          docker-compose --env-file=compose.env --file=compose-tests.yaml build
          docker-compose --env-file=compose.env --file=compose-tests.yaml up
```

I've forced some errors like `NameError` and `flake8`/`pylint` non 0 returns(I've expected that this values are been handled as errors).

Even forcing this errors the actions was passed! I expected that the action only pass when all test containers was passed or returns 0.

How to configure it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try `docker-compose up` with `--abort-on-container-exit`. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/.